# How can I build my unity android project using Intellij?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, intellij-idea

I'm developing an android messenger using unity.

I couldn’t build it in unity.(When I try, I receive a lot of gradle-related errors)

So I’m trying to export my project somewhere else.

I already know that it’s possible to export a project and build it in android studio,

but, it possible to build my unity project in Intellij?

I have no knowledge about Intellij.

Any sort of help will be well appreciated!

Comment: Errors building in Unity are usually pretty easy to fix. Use the google play resolver to fix the dependencies and you're good. Building in Android Studio can work but can also be much messier. What benefit do you thing there is trying to build it in an unsupported IDE that you have no experience with?